# R mutating along a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df<- data_frame(first =seq(1:10), second = seq(1:10))
ldf <- list(df, df, df, df, df)
names(ldf) <- c('alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta', 'echo')
```

I have this list of dataframes and I am attempting to apply the mutate function to each dataframe but I get a "not compatible with STRSXP" error that I am confused about.

here is my code that gives me the error.

```
for( i in seq_along(ldf)){
 ldf[[i]] <- mutate( ldf[[i]], NewColumn1= ldf[[i]][1]/(ldf[[i]][2] *2),
                               NewColumn2= ldf[[i]][1]/(ldf[[i]][2] * 3))
}
```

My intention is that the for loop goes to the first dataframe. It applys the mutate function and creates a new column called "NewColumn1" that divides the first column by two times the second column. It does something similar for the next column.

Am I in the right ballpark with this code or can I not use mutate when looping though dfs in a list?

Comment: Try: `ldf2 <- lapply(ldf, function(x) {
    mutate(x, 
           NewColumn1 = first/(second * 2),
           NewColumn2 = first/(second * 3))
})`. You can also use the `map` function from the `purrr` package.

Comment: If they're in the same format anyway, just use `ldf %>% bind_rows(.id = 'id')` to make them into a normal data.frame.

Answer (score 16):

You seem to be on the right track, but the way you're substituting the elements of your original list is a bit faulty. While there are multiple ways this could be achieved, the following are in the realm of what you started with:

#### for-loop

```
for (df_name in names(ldf)) {
    ldf[[df_name]] <- mutate(ldf[[df_name]],
           new_col_one=first/(second * 2),
           new_col_two=first/(second * 3))
}
```

This actually overwrites the original list.

#### lapply

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) {
    mutate(x,
           new_col_one=first/(second * 2),
           new_col_two=first/(second * 3))
})
```

This will create a new list

#### Map

```
Map(function(x) {
    mutate(x,
           new_col_one=first/(second * 2),
           new_col_two=first/(second * 3))
}, ldf)
```

This will create a new list, as well.

You can also look into [`map`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) from the `purrr` package.

I hope one of these serves a purpose.

Comment: `for` is bad style here, and `Map` is generally used for multivariate functions, though it does work fine as univariate.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an option with `map` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ldf %>%
   map(~mutate(., NewColumn1 = first/(second*2), NewColumn2 = first/(second*3)))
```

Comment: may be you answered this already ....if not I can post a question. Is there a way to map mutate to all columns without specifying column name ? For instance instead of naming `NewColumn1`,`NewColumn2` can we dynamically name them as well as select columns for `first/100` `second/100`..can some function `x/100` and x is all columns in that lsdf ?

Comment: @user5249203. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415561/mutate-all-numeric-variables-with-condition/57415587#57415587). where you need to change the `mutate_if` to `mutate_at(vars(...), list(New = ~ ./100))`

Comment: @user5249203. here, you can use `mutate_all` i.e. `map(ldf,  ~ .x %>% mutate_all(list(New = ~ ./100)))`