# Mutate all numeric variables with condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset.

```
 structure(list(Monate = structure(c(5L, 4L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 
    2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "Dezember", 
    "Februar", "Januar", "Juli", "Juni", "Mai", "März", "November", 
    "Oktober", "September"), class = "factor"), `06:00:00-00:59:59` = c(1.23650890285152, 
    1, 0.941959539059369, 0.89618038635695, 0.839845976370379, 0.75789368475892, 
    0.745357979199247, 0.72726835342115, 0.852384444043199, 0.909567524854388, 
    0.927385464132519, 0.86987613403725), `06:00:00-08:59:59` = c(0.28594460357425, 
    0.28900629033325, 0.315719841587, 0.2955345904455, 0.273041491484, 
    0.26127195229025, 0.23431503049, 0.22167349349575, 0.2603577651915, 
    0.27084189072775, 0.2653932948955, 0.246001500902), `09:00:00-12:59:59` = c(0.48396300341875, 
    0.4767075864935, 0.46442852744125, 0.4497871047545, 0.4088477917855, 
    0.39907331646225, 0.387052062652, 0.3717692228805, 0.39248244105925, 
    0.422900151297, 0.4111808332435, 0.41687239709375), `13:00:00-16:59:59` = c(0.80304931519625, 
    0.7588016605465, 0.66548492801425, 0.6354014724685, 0.670969199053, 
    0.58076568424625, 0.67418744877975, 0.5756792489565, 0.66766765226025, 
    0.642654220031, 0.665735145053, 0.64571729495575), `17:00:00-19:59:59` = c(1.44101730420325, 
    1.35385679874675, 1.2576760885645, 1.1478274405785, 1.04871946565175, 
    0.96498516399125, 0.9775891903885, 0.9959819200865, 1.0805495717725, 
    1.2042836233065, 1.29337213775425, 1.17905118172475), `20:00:00-22:59:59` = c(2.7590124723295, 
    2.1458514208575, 2.00826846019375, 1.91719758837025, 1.7425652515095, 
    1.509920737758, 1.3851778869395, 1.43588733645025, 1.8753361739725, 
    2.03981388252275, 2.013661241837, 1.79544669375925), `23:00:00-00:59:59` = c(1.92548355216275, 
    0.926693335582, 0.921407232611, 0.92680356666725, 0.87033626954225, 
    0.81832375651025, 0.75033232500425, 0.7289554638715, 0.79565322269175, 
    0.85606802035675, 0.90891474021375, 0.94322847859325)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L))
```

I want to build index values where I set one month to "1".

```
saisonindex <- RWavg %>%
    mutate(`06:00:00-00:59:59` = `06:00:00-00:59:59` / `06:00:00-00:59:59`[Monate == "Februar"])
saisonindex

      Monate 06:00:00-00:59:59 06:00:00-08:59:59 09:00:00-12:59:59 13:00:00-16:59:59 17:00:00-19:59:59 20:00:00-22:59:59 23:00:00-00:59:59
1     Januar         1.2365089         0.2859446         0.4839630         0.8030493         1.4410173          2.759012         1.9254836
2    Februar         1.0000000         0.2890063         0.4767076         0.7588017         1.3538568          2.145851         0.9266933
3       März         0.9419595         0.3157198         0.4644285         0.6654849         1.2576761          2.008268         0.9214072
4      April         0.8961804         0.2955346         0.4497871         0.6354015         1.1478274          1.917198         0.9268036
5        Mai         0.8398460         0.2730415         0.4088478         0.6709692         1.0487195          1.742565         0.8703363
6       Juni         0.7578937         0.2612720         0.3990733         0.5807657         0.9649852          1.509921         0.8183238
7       Juli         0.7453580         0.2343150         0.3870521         0.6741874         0.9775892          1.385178         0.7503323
8     August         0.7272684         0.2216735         0.3717692         0.5756792         0.9959819          1.435887         0.7289555
9  September         0.8523844         0.2603578         0.3924824         0.6676677         1.0805496          1.875336         0.7956532
10   Oktober         0.9095675         0.2708419         0.4229002         0.6426542         1.2042836          2.039814         0.8560680
11  November         0.9273855         0.2653933         0.4111808         0.6657351         1.2933721          2.013661         0.9089147
12  Dezember         0.8698761         0.2460015         0.4168724         0.6457173         1.1790512          1.795447         0.9432285
```

I want to do this for all numeric columns dynamically, I guess `mutate_if(is.numeric)` will do this, but I can not get my head around how it might work which the condition in the bracket.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `mutate_if`, specify the `~` and then subset the column value where the 'Monate' is "Februar"

```
library(dplyr)
RWavg %>% 
   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ./.[Monate == "Februar"])
```

---

In `base R`, just subset the row, get the lengths right, divide and update the columns

```
RWavg[-1] <- RWavg[-1]/RWavg[RWavg$Monate == 'Februar', -1][col(RWavg[-1])]
```